# Facebook Debugger Error no data was scraped

Tags: php, facebook

Here's the scenario: I paste a link (http://abantenextgen.com/news/weather-update/10162/pagasa-dost-severe-weather-bulletin-number-eleven.html) in the URL Debugger and it returns an error:

> Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.

When I check the Scraped URL, it displays the complete html output. 
But when click the Fetch new scrape information it will now display the right output.

Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

The website uses Laravel 5 as it's framework. PHP version 5.4. Just in case.

You can check other link here:

```
http://abantenextgen.com/test/test.php
http://abantenextgen.com/test/test1.php
http://abantenextgen.com/test/test2.php
http://abantenextgen.com/test/test3.php
http://abantenextgen.com/test/test4.php
http://abantenextgen.com/test/test5.php
```

[image]

Comment: It just worked when I tried it. Click on "Fetch new scrape information" if this error happens for another page.

Comment: @stevenw It will work there. What if a new article is posted? They will need to repeat the process again and again just to make sure that the visitors will share the article with right image and description

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate a call to scrape the newly created content/article once it is saved as described at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

Example:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://abantenextgen.com/new/page.html&scrape=true
```

where `http://abantenextgen.com/new/page.html` is just an example of the new article's url.

Comment: how can I make it automatically? For example I share an article using addthis with pre-determined url.

Comment: Like I wrote, you can write some server-side code which triggers the "publication" to the Facebook Scraper once the new content/article page is created in your system. AddThis etc. has *nothing* to do with this.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Thanks.
Another question, normally it was suppose to work just like that, What happened to Facebook URL Debugger?

Comment: Facebook URL Debugger works... What should be the problem? It you click on "Fetch" the URL is scraped.

Comment: No no. Last time I develop a dynamic content, every time I test the URL Debugger, once I paste the URL and debug it, it will work right away. No problem occurred. But now, I need to Fetch new scrape information before it work.